# Define what value to put in a Spring cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

Using Spring cache abstraction, I want to cache the results of `itemExists` method calls. When an item is inserted by `insertItem` method, I want to put the value `true` in the cache.

```
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

   private static final String CACHE_EXISTS_NAME = "existsCache";

   @Override
   @Cacheable(CACHE_EXISTS_NAME)
   public boolean itemExists(Long id) {
       // access the repository the check whether the item exists
   }

   @Override
   @CachePut(cacheNames = CACHE_EXISTS_NAME, key = "#item.id")
   public Item insertItem(Item item) {
       ...
   }

}
```

How can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Its not supported. A work around could be to define `@Cacheable` on say your dao's finder method and then call it from itemExists method:

In the DAO:

```
   @Cacheable(CACHE_EXISTS_NAME)
   public Item findById(Long id) {
       //..
   }
```

In your service:

```
   @Override
   public boolean itemExists(Long id) {
       if(null == dao.findById(id)) {
           return false;
       } else {
           return true;
       }
   }
```

Note that since the method calls are proxied to support this, defining and calling finder inside the same object (service class in this case) will result in annotation being ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a good idea, but I can't put @Cacheable on repository layer. An option would be to create another class that does it, but it would be pretty ugly. Before doing it, I will talk to Spring team.

Answer (score -1):

I find your use case a bit disturbing. If you want to see if a particular item is in the cache, why don't you ask the cache rather than having those convoluted indirections? You could inject the `Cache` instance and asks for its content.

I guess that changing your code to the following might work but I really do not recommend that:

```
@Override
@CachePut(cacheNames = CACHE_EXISTS_NAME, key = "#item.id")
public boolean insertItem(Item item) {
  ...
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I understand your point but it is annoying to know that if an item is successfully inserted, it obviously exists and considering cache features, I have to check the repository. Unfortunately, I can't change the code as you mentioned because I have two caches: one for items and another for "exists flags".

Comment: What's the point of doing that anyway? Seriously, I just don't understand why you would expose caching in a public API.

Comment: In the real scenario, I have an ItemService that has methods to insert, update, retrieve and check the existence of items. The implementation needs to delegate these tasks to a repository. Obviously, there is an implicit requirement to do these tasks as fast as possible. So how can I do it? Accessing the repository only when really needed. Users of ItemService won't be aware of caching.

Comment: Change `itemExists(Long id)` to `findById(Long id`) and cache it as usual. Replace your call from (`if itemExists(id)` to `if findbyId(id) != null`). Seriously, that's going to do _exactly_ the same thing and wouldn't need to map the same keys in two different caches.

Comment: I've tried initially to put findById(id) != null in itemExists implementation, so I realized that cache does not work when calling internal methods. I created this question to avoid removing itemExists method since it is used by many external users. So my next step will be to deprecate itemExists method and describe it in javadoc (probably the itemExists  was created based on Spring CrudRepository exists method) :( Thank you anyway.